# Why DC and C flag set when using compare instruction

Tags: assembly, pic

I use `PIC24` for this

```
;cp{.b} f

mov #0x0003,W1
mov W1,0x0830
mov #0x0002,W0
cp 0x0830  ; DC=1 , N=0 , OV=0, Z=0, C=1 
mov #0x0003,W0
cp 0x0830  ; DC=1 , N=0 , OV=0, Z=1, C=1`
```

for this one I have no idea why `DC` is set because `3-2=1` or `3-3=0` have nothing to do with bit `7` and `8`, okay `C=1` because no borrow then `c` is not clear

and for this

```
mov #0x0003,W1
bclr 0x0042,#0    ;C=0
cpb W1,#0x2       ;DC=1,N=0,OV=0,Z=0,C=1`
```

why `Z` is not set ? I thought `3-2-1=0` then `Z` should be `1` and for `DC` and `C` still has no idea

Comment: both DC and C are carry out bits right?  if there is no borrow then carry out is a 1, if the architecture doesnt invert it into a borrow bit then they should be set for these operations yes?  since bits 4 on up are zeros then both the DC and C should match from what I am reading (one is half carry at bit 4 or 8 the other is the msbit carry out).

Comment: from what I am looking at bclr does not affect flags.

Comment: some mov's do but I think this one is not one of them.

Comment: yes dc is half carry and c is carry flag

Comment: I think the process of 3-2 is 3+(-2) then we will get 0000 0000 0000 0011 + 1111 1111 1111 1110 and that's why DC and C flag are set

but i'm still confused about cpb instructions

Comment: cpb is (W1)-2-0 which is 3~2 + 1 isn't it ?

Comment: CBB{.B} Wb,#lit5 is  Wb - #lit5 – BORROW (~C) so yes you are right it is 3 - 2 - 1 if C is zero going in, so there is a borrow 3 + (~2) + 0   0011 + 1101 + 0  and the C and DC flags make sense but Z not so much.  If the C flag going in is actually a 1 then 0011 + 1101 + 1 is 0001, and all three flags make sense Z, C, DC.